# create table syntax error in Microsoft Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here is my code, i'm trying to make multiple tables:

```
Create Table Order_t
(
Id AutoIncrement Not Null,
OrderDate DateTime Not Null,
CustId Int Not Null,
Primary Key(Id),
Foreign Key(CustId) References Customer_t(Id)
(;
Create Table PersonRole_t
(
PersonRoleID Autoincrement Not Null,
Person_ID int Not Null,
Primary Key(PersonRoleID, Person_ID),
Foreign Key(Person_ID) References Person_T(Person_ID)
(;
Create Table Product_t
(
Id Text(10) Not Null,
Name Text(30) Not Null,
Description Text(30),
Finish Text(30),
UnitPrice Currency Not Null,
Primary Key(Id)
) ;
```

Whenever I run it in Microsoft Access, I get an error in the CREATE TABLE statement (it highlights the PersonRole_T table definition). Not sure what to do, rather new to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CLOSE` *parenthesis* at the end of `CREATE` Table statement instead of `OPEN` *parenthesis*

```
Create Table Order_t
(
Id AutoIncrement Not Null,
OrderDate DateTime Not Null,
CustId Int Not Null,
Primary Key(Id),
Foreign Key(CustId) References Customer_t(Id)
); -- Not (;

Create Table PersonRole_t
(
PersonRoleID Autoincrement Not Null,
Person_ID int Not Null,
Primary Key(PersonRoleID, Person_ID),
Foreign Key(Person_ID) References Person_T(Person_ID)
); -- Not (;
```

Comment: Just to state the obvious for the OP, Access SQL syntax does not support comments so the `-- Not (;` part needs to be removed when being executed.

Answer (score 0):

The table `Person_T` with a key of `Person_ID` needs to exist before the `References Person_T(Person_ID)` statement can execute. Based on your naming convention, I would guess the statement should rather be `References Person_T(Id)`.

Consider changing your naming convention so that a data element does not change its name depending its location realtive to tables/views. Also consider whether the `_t` suffix is worth the bother.

@Prdp's point about the close parens is valid too.